# SMTPClIENT send through second lan port

Tags: c#

As of right now I have a server client program that is not connected to a gateway... one to one connection. However the user has the ability to send a log via email. The computer has 2 lan ports... first one being for the program and the second for if the user wants internet connectivity. How can I set the smtp object to send via the second lan and not the first?

Answer (score 0):

Got it... binded a endpoint callback. Works like a charm.